# Understanding that the existence of a Schauder basis implies the approximation property

Tags: functional-analysis, projection, schauder-basis

I found a proof that  the existence of a Schauder basis implies the bounded approximation property on Banach spaces. ( J.Lindenstrauss, L.Tzafriri; classical Banach spaces; p.12).

> Let $\{P_i\}$ be the projections associated to the basis $\{x_n\}$ and $A = \sup\limits_i ||P_i||$. For every compact set of vectors $K\subset X$ and every $\varepsilon >0$ we can find $i = i(\varepsilon,K)$ such that the distance $$d(x, span\{x_1, ... , x_i\}) < \varepsilon / 2A; x\in K $$
>   Then obviously, $||x-P_ix|| < \varepsilon $, for every $x\in K$

I don't understand why hes using $\varepsilon/2A$ as the bound for the distance. Wouldn't $\varepsilon$ be sufficient because $||x-P_ix|| = d(x, span\{x_1, ... , x_i\})$?

Comment: I'm not sure your equality holds. For $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n x_n$, $P_i(x)=\sum_{n=1}^i\alpha_n x_n$. In $\ell_1$, take $x_2=e_1+e_2$ and $x_i=e_i$, $i\ne2$ (here, $(e_i)$ is the standard unit vector basis of $\ell_1$). Then $(x_i)$ is a basis of $\ell_1$, $d(x_2,\text{span}\{x_1\})=1$, but $\Vert x_2-P_1(x_2)\Vert=\Vert x_2\Vert=2$.

Comment: @DavidMitra in your example, if $d(x_2, \mathrm{span}\{x_1\})=1=\varepsilon/2A$ then doesn't that mean $\varepsilon=2$? Which is what you get for $\|x_2-P_1(x_2)\|$?  (And so a very good example of why the $2A$ is important!)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem was a confusion in definition of a projection. I thought that they can only map to the closest point in a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this is saying that the $\varepsilon$ depends on $A:=\sup_i \|P_i\|$.

Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary we can, of course, just write $\varepsilon$ in the inequality and know that we are correct.  This hides the dependency on $A$ though, and for subsequent applications that can be a bad thing.  Note that the number of vectors you need to take in the linear span *also* depends on this $\varepsilon$.  If $A$ is very close to $1$ then you will need (many) more vectors in your span than if $A\approx 10^5$ (for example).